# separating data access with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm just getting to know elasticsearch and I'm wondering if it suits my case at all:

Considering a system where companies (with multiple employees) can register and administer their clients, and send documents to their clients.

Now, I want to enable companies to search their documents - but ONLY theirs, not the documents of other companies. In other words: how to separate the data of those companies for searches? How can this be implemented with elasticsearch?

Is this separation to be handled by elasticsearch itself? I.e. there is some mapping between the companies in my system and a related user for elasticsearch.
Or is this to be handled by the backend of my system? I.e. the backend somehow decides (how?) to show only search results for that particular company. So there would be just one user, namely the backend of my system, that accesses and filters the results of elasticsearch. But is this sensible?

I'm sure there is a wealth of information about this out there. Please just give me a hint, because I don't know what to search for. Searches for elasticsearch authentication/authorization, for example, only yield results about who gains access to the search system in general - not about a pattern to solve this separation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elasticsearch on its own does not support Authorization and Authentication, you need to add this via plugins, of which there are two that I know of. Shield is the official solution, which is part of the X-Pack and you need to pay Elastic if you want to use it. [SearchGuard](https://floragunn.com/searchguard/) is an open source alternative with enterprise upgrades that you can buy.
Both of these enable you to define fine grained access rights for different users. What you'd probably want to do is give every company an index of their own for their documents and then restrict their user to only be able to read/write that index. Or if you absolutely want all documents in one index, you can add document level restrictions as well, so that everybody queries the same index but only gets results returned for their company. Depending on how many companies you expect to service this might make more sense in order to not have too many indices and shards, but I'd suspect that an index per company would be the best way to go.

Without these plugins you would need to resort to something on the http-layer, for example an nginx reverse proxy that filters requests based on the index names contained in the urls or something, but I'd severely advise against this, lots of pain lies that way!

Comment: thanks for your answer, Sönke! got me reading further and I think I'm getting the idea. Have a nice evening!